# Phaser // Javascript // Player is not defined

Tags: javascript, var, phaser-framework

Everything is working, except in the *update* function, when I put back the `var player`, it  doesn't recognize it:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: player is not defined"

(I'm also not sure for the animation) (Mario is the player, it's a mario level)

Here is my code:

```
var SandBox = {

    preload:function(){

        //this.game
        console.log("preload Sand Box");

        this.game.load.image('platform', 'assets/platform.png');
        this.game.load.spritesheet('mario', 'assets/mario.png', 32, 32 , 12);
        this.game.load.image('coinbox', 'assets/coinbox.png');
    },

    create:function(){
        console.log("create Sand Box");

        var imageHeight = this.game.cache.getImage("platform").height;
        this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        var worldHeight = this.game.world.height;


        var ground = this.game.add.sprite(0, worldHeight - imageHeight, 'platform');
        var platform = this.game.add.sprite(250, 285, 'platform');
        var platform = this.game.add.sprite(-250, 145, 'platform');
        var platform = this.game.add.sprite(280, 285, 'coinbox');
        var player = this.game.add.sprite(32, 100, 'mario');

        this.game.physics.enable(ground);
        this.game.physics.enable(platform);
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(player);

        player.frame = 5;
        ground.body.immovable = true;
        platform.body.immovable = true;        
        player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
        player.body.gravity.y = 300;
        player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;


        player.animations.add('left', [0, 1, 2, 3], 10, true);
        player.animations.add('right', [5, 6, 7, 8], 10, true);

    },

    update:function(){
        console.log("update Sand Box");
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(player);

        var hitPlatform = this.game.physics.arcade.collide(player, ground); // << THESE FUNCTIONS
    }


}
```

Comment: `player` is out-of-scope. Declare it outside the function.

Comment: I am sorry, i dont know how to declare it outside the function. Can you tell me the line i need to put it please ?

Answer (score 2):

The [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of variable `player` in thr snippet is local to the function it is in. One can move the declaration (with [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)) for `player` outside of the `sandbox` object:

```
var player;
var sandbox = {
    create: function() {
         //... skipping lines ...
         player = this.game.add.sprite(32, 100, 'mario');
    }, 
    Update: function() {
          //use player here
          var hitPlatform = this.game.physics.arcade.collide(player, ground); // << THESE FUNCTIONS

    }
};
```

Or make it part of the object:

```
 var sandbox = {
        create: function() {
             //... skipping lines ...
             this.player = this.game.add.sprite(32, 100, 'mario');
      }, 
      Update: function() {
            //... skipping lines ...
            //use this.player here
            var hitPlatform = this.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.player, ground);
       }
 };
```

Comment: Hey ! It is working, but there is another error :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Comment: okay - I don't see any calls to that method in your code so I suspect it is in the Phaser code... that may be something you ask in a separate question, unless you can create another example (e.g. in [plunker](http://plnkr.co), [codepen](http://codepen.io) or even a [SO snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/))